# numpy structured array with bytes field

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, unicode, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to build a structured numpy array with a field that is a *named* bytes field (type `4b`, not unicode).

```
import numpy as np 
dtype = np.dtype([('count', 'u8'), ('name', '4b')], align=True)
a = np.asarray([(10, b'test')], dtype=dtype)
print(a.dtype)
```

I receive the error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'test'`

Now, if i change the bytes field to unicode,

```
import numpy as np 
dtype = np.dtype([('count', 'u8'), ('name', 'U4')], align=True)
a = np.asarray([(10, 'test')], dtype=dtype)
print(a.dtype)
```

this does not result in an error and I get the output:

`{'names':['count','name'], 'formats':['<u8','<U4'], 'offsets':[0,8], 'itemsize':24, 'aligned':True}`

But to me this is a hack since I specifically just want bytes.

**Question: How can I get a named bytes field on my structured numpy array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `S` type string to work with byte strings:

```
>>> dtype = np.dtype([('count', 'u8'), ('name', 'S4')], align=True)
>>> a = np.array([(10, b'test')], dtype=dtype)
>>> a
array([(10, b'test')],
      dtype={'names':['count','name'], 'formats':['<u8','S4'], 'offsets':[0,8], 'itemsize':16, 'aligned':True})
```